# Segmentation Fault when using FOR loop but not when using WHILE in an implementation of qsort on an array of pointers

Tags: c, for-loop, segmentation-fault, qsort, kernighan-and-ritchie

I currently am beginning at C programming, my long term objective being teaching myself reverse engineering, and I am following the excellent book by Denis M. Ritchie. I chose this book despite it being written in the 90s because of the great care the authors paid to explanations and examples throughout it.
Anyway, I was playing with the quicksort algorithm the authors described in section 5.6, and tried to rewrite it by recall, but had trouble because of a segmentation fault that I tried to debug with gdb. The code was :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 10000

void sort(int **, int, int);

int main(){
    int tab[MAX]={18,7,43,72,2365,743,234,3215,13,456}, i;
    int *ptrtab[MAX];
    for (i=0; i<MAX && tab[i]>0; i++){
        ptrtab[i]=&tab[i];
    }   
    sort(ptrtab, 0, i-1);
    for (;i>0;i--) printf ("%d\n",*ptrtab[i]);
    return 0;
}

void sort(int **ptrtab,int gauche,int droite){
    int i, dernier;
    void echanger(int **, int, int);
    if (gauche>=droite) return;
    dernier=gauche;
    for (i=gauche+1; i<=droite; i++){
        if (*ptrtab[i]< *ptrtab[gauche])
            echanger(ptrtab, ++dernier, i);
    }
    echanger(ptrtab, gauche, dernier);
    sort(ptrtab,dernier+1,droite);
    sort(ptrtab,gauche, dernier);
}

void echanger(int **ptrtab,int a,int b){
    int *temp=ptrtab[a];
    ptrtab[a]=ptrtab[b];
    ptrtab[b]=temp;
}
```

Long story short, after identifying the line in cause (`for (;i>0;i--) printf ("%d\n",*ptrtab[i]);`)I put a break on it, and the segmentation fault crashed the program on the first iteration of the for loop, and `printf` wasn't executed. So I just changed this line in my code to put a `while` loop instead :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 10000

void sort(int **, int, int);

int main(){
    int tab[MAX]={18,7,43,72,2365,743,234,3215,13,456}, i;
    int *ptrtab[MAX];
    for (i=0; i<MAX && tab[i]>0; i++){
        ptrtab[i]=&tab[i];
    }   
    sort(ptrtab, 0, i-1);
    while (i>0) printf ("%d\n",*ptrtab[--i]);
    return 0;
}

void sort(int **ptrtab,int gauche,int droite){
    int i, dernier;
    void echanger(int **, int, int);
    if (gauche>=droite) return;
    dernier=gauche;
    for (i=gauche+1; i<=droite; i++){
        if (*ptrtab[i]< *ptrtab[gauche])
            echanger(ptrtab, ++dernier, i);
    }
    echanger(ptrtab, gauche, dernier);
    sort(ptrtab,dernier+1,droite);
    sort(ptrtab,gauche, dernier);
}

void echanger(int **ptrtab,int a,int b){
    int *temp=ptrtab[a];
    ptrtab[a]=ptrtab[b];
    ptrtab[b]=temp;
}
```

And this code works now. 
I know there must be quite a few errors throughout my code as I am just a beginner, but I can't grasp the reason why changing from a `for` to a `while` loop made a difference...
Note that I am using GCC on ubuntu 16.04.

Thank you all for your attention, and sorry for the rambling.
Kind regards,
S. A.

Comment: The book does not teach modern and standard C.

Comment: @Olaf thank you for your comment. Would you know some e-books or tutorials that do?

Comment: The standard is a good read. But there is a book-list on SO somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your while loop is actually different to the for loop. The while loop decrements i *before* using it; the for loop does not.

Comment: Adding the sentinel to tab is one approach. Another is to avoid defining `MAX` altogether (just write `tab[] = { ...  }`), not bother with the ptrtab array (just write `tab +i` everywhere you would have written `ptrtab[i]`), and iterate with `for( int *start=tab; start < tab + sizeof tab / sizeof *tab; start++)`

Comment: @WilliamPursell: The sentinel is already implemented. The first loop is made to run only as long as `... && tab[i]>0`.

Comment: @jarmod: Aren't remaining elements in an arrays that have no initializer implicitely initialized to 0?

Comment: @Gerhardh Yes, I believe you are correct, my mistake. Global scope arrays are obviously zeroed but looks like automatics with fewer initializers than the width of the array (e.g. int arr[10] = {1,2,3}) are also trail-initialized to zero. Have removed that part of my answer, thanks.

Comment: @jarmod Thanks for your answer, I chose it because you answered first and it was concise and to the point :)

Comment: @WilliamPursell thanks for your comment :) You are right, I used an array of pointers despite the code didn't need it. It was just to push myself to use pointers to become more familiar with them. I will look up your method too, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
for (;i>0;i--) printf ("%d\n",*ptrtab[i]);
```

The loop starts with the last value of `i` from the previous loop, where either it reaches the end of the array (so `i` will be `MAX`), or indexes `tab` at a point where it is zero.

In the first case, `ptrtab[MAX]` will be indexed, which is invalid, in the second case an uninitialized entry of `ptrtab` will be used, which, being an automatic variable, will have a random value (points to a random memory location, which will likely be invalid (undefined behaviour).

Comment: Maybe, but it is more likely that `i` starts at the point where `tab[i]>0` is no longer TRUE and `ptrtab[i]` is not initialized.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie thank you for your answer. Using printf("%d\n",*ptrtab[i-1]) indeed fixed the problem!